# Remove part of a string and return two split strings in python

Tags: python, regex

The function would be:

```
def split_string(string, removal)
```

For example, if I have the string ABCDEFGHIJK and removal string DEF, the program would remove DEF from the string and return the LEFT and RIGHT resulting strings. In this case, it would be ABC and GHIJK.

How would I go about doing this using Regex? One idea I had was to find the target "removal" string in the original string and replace it with a space, then parse that string and return the two strings.

Comment: So did you try implementing that idea? What happened? An empty function definition doesn’t count as a [mcve] and SO isn’t a tutorial service.

Comment: Do you want to split a string and keep the seperators?

Comment: `print(re.split("DEF","ABCDEFGHIJK"))`

Comment: Do you even need regex here? `str.split` should do. This reeks of homework.

Comment: Use `str.split("DEF", 1)` to only split into 2 parts.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do

```
str = "ABCDEFGHIJK";

print str.split("DEF");
```

see the [online compiler](https://ideone.com/6KoM31)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how (or why) you would do that with a regex. This is a much simpler solution.

```
def split_string(string, removal):
    return string.split(removal)

leftString, rightString = split_string("abcdefghijk", "def")
```